# Serialize derived (unknown) types

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, derived-class

lets start this thread with a bunch of assumptions:
first assumption: we have a library (*.dll) which contains the following code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    }
}

public class Foo { public string name;}
```

second assumption: we got a class that derives from Foo, let´s call it Bar.

```
public class Bar : Foo { }
```

This class is located outside the library.

Now comes the magic into it: the Bar-class is loaded via Reflection so we do not know of its existence during compile-time. Also the `XmlSerializer` does not know anything of the derived class and because we are in a completely different library we cannot simply add `XmlInclude` here because we cannot change the code of the `Foo`-class. So is there any way to use the existing `XmlSerializer` on an instance of the `Bar`-class (I know that by the current implementation `ser` wouldn´t be visible at all to any outer code, but lets take this aside and assume that we CAN access the serializer from within the `Bar`-class)?

Can this furthermore be achieved by using attributes to the `Bar`-class ([System.Xml.Serialization...] in front of the class´ definition) ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these restrictions exist for *wierd* reasons and that your XmlSerializer needs a type argument then you'll need to get the runtime type of the argument.

```
var barInstance = However().You().Reflect().To().Get().Bar();

// The runtime type
var barType = barInstance.GetType();

var ser = XmlSerializer(barType);
```

typeof(T) gets the type at compile time but, since you don't have access to that, you'll need Obj.GetType();

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I already pointed out the Serializer which I want to use already exists within the library. Having said this I cannot re-declare it with a new type-Attribute.

Comment: You're already passing it a type at runtime: Foo. typeof just generates the argument at compile time, the XmlSerializer is still instantiated at runtime with that type argument. You will need to use GetType() to get the runtime type of something.